# Laravel Mix - unexpected token error

Tags: laravel, ecmascript-6, babeljs, laravel-mix

I am trying to run this

```
Vue.component(
      'async-webpack-example',
      () => import('./my-async-component')l
    )
```

I get this error but thought mix could compile ES2015 syntax?

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (30:8)

  28 | Vue.component(
  29 |   'async-webpack-example',
> 30 |   () => import('./my-async-component')
     |         ^
  31 | )
```

Answer (score 1):

try add `System`. I think you might be using an earlier release of Webpack 2. `System.import()` was deprecated in favor of `import()` in webpack 2.1.0-beta.28.

[Change System.import() to import() #2163](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2163)

```
Vue.component(
      'async-webpack-example',
      () => System.import('./my-async-component')l
    )
```